# “Good” properties of transparent conducting oxides

Tags: reference-request, conductivity, absorption, semiconductors, thin-films

I'm a computer scientist and I'm trying to figure out which are the key properties that define a “good” acting transparent conducting oxide (TCO) in order to consider several possible features to create machine-learning models for eventually discovering new TCOs.

I've already read that a “good” TCO should have a high electrical conductivity with a low absorption of visible light (which, in fact, makes it transparent), so a good measure of the TCO behavior could be defined as

$$\frac{\sigma}{\alpha} = -\frac{1}{R_\mathrm{s}\ln(T + R)},$$

where $R_\mathrm{s}$ is the sheet resistance in ohms per square, $T$ is the total visible transmission, and $R$ the total visible reflectance. By my understanding, also films thickness plays some role and it influences the values of $\sigma$ and $\alpha$. In particular, the more thickness I have, the more figure of merit $\sigma/\alpha$ increases and it results in a better behaving TCO.

Since I'm diving into chemistry for the first time, I wanted to ask you some suggestions about the topic, as well as eventually where to find interesting data about it.

Comment: You have not covered hardness, refractive index, residual stress from deposition, impurity/defect impact on color, reactivity, moisture resistance, standard solvent resistance, or likely another half dozen or more characteristics that make something 'good'.

Comment: Workability in thin films surely add to the list above